# Javascript engines and ajax

Tags: xmlhttprequest, v8, javascript-engine

I'm reading about JS engines in modern browsers (V8, SpiderMonkey, Chakra...)
There isn't any information (or I missed it somehow) about Ajax (XHR request) optimization.

Is there such a thing?

P.S. Maybe there isn't any space for the optimization itself, and I would like to know if that is the case.

Comment: Can't get any simpler than instanciating an object, calling a couple methods, assigning a handler...

Comment: Well, one thing that comes into my mind is optimizing form of Json request/response, serialization/deserialization...